# How to attribute lines with IDs of touching polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, intersection, line, identity

I have two shapefiles: one contains streets of a city and one contains blocks (i.e. polygons bounded by the streets). I would like to have the streets attributed with the IDs of the left and right polygons.

Is there a way to do that in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from the [Identity tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=1338&pid=1336&topicname=Identity_%28Analysis%29) on the Analysis toolbar:

> "Checking or setting the Relationship
>   parameter to KEEP_RELATIONSHIPS will
>   write additional spatial relationships
>   between the Input Features and the
>   Identity Features to the output
>   feature class. If the inputs are lines
>   and the Identity Features are
>   polygons, there will be two additional
>   fields, LEFT_poly and RIGHT_poly."

I think you can get what you need with this tool. It needs an ArcInfo license.

Comment: OK,I will check that out on Monday,when I have access to arcgis, but from the docs it seems that it should do the trick.

Comment: Yup, this got me *almost* what I wanted. It split up the segments into separate ones, each having one attribute for a polygon, but from that I joined them and got exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a buffer on your street shapefile and do a spatial query / join on the block shapefile. I am not an ArcGis specialist so I can't give you a more detailed answer unfortunately ...

Comment: That is what I tried first, but could not get the results that I wanted.